# adding jars to your program

Tags: java, executable-jar

i have a simple Demo.java file in **D:\jarConcepts** directory:

```
import javax.swing.* ;

class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("") ;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) ;

        Class c = null ;
        try{
            c = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;

            //com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class is in a jar file
            //whose class path is set in the environment variable(explicitly done by me)

            //when i am executing Demo.class using java command, it displays frame with OK title
            //but if i execute this by creating a jar, it enables to load the
            //com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class,
            //thus displaying frame with Sorry title

            frame.setTitle("OK") ;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            frame.setTitle("Sorry") ;   
        }

        frame.setVisible(true) ;
    }
}
```

**I prepared a manifest.txt file in D:\jarConcepts with following text :**

Main-Class: Demo

Class-Path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Tools for 5.0\java\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar

**when, i create a jar file from the same directory using**

jar -cvfm Demo.jar manifest.txt .class

**following is the output :**

added manifest
adding: Demo.class(in = 743) (out= 505)(deflated 32%)

**But, when i execute the jar file generated, it shows an error message,**

Could not find the main class. Program will exit.

**i don't understand why this is happening, coz, when i creating the jar file with the following manifest code :**

Main-Class: Demo

**i am getting a perfectly executable Demo.jar, the only problem is that it is not loading the Driver class from the ]
class path and when i am trying to add the path in the manifest, it's not working......
plz help.......**

Answer (score 1):

The spaces are interpreted as delimiters and the entries should be relative:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Main%20Attributes

> Class-Path :
>
> The value of this attribute specifies
>   the ***relative URLs*** of the
>   extensions or libraries that this
>   application or extension needs. URLs
>   are ***separated by one or more spaces***.

Comment: so what url i have to give if my jar is in
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Tools for 5.0\java\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar
directory....

Comment: You should copy the jar to a location relative to your jar (e.g. lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar) - in theory, you would have to do something like this when you create your deployment package for your app.  In a pinch, you could also try "file:///C:/Program%20Files/MySQL/CMySQL%20Tools%20for%205.0/java/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar".

Comment: Thinking of packaging - I've used ant to merge the dependency jars into my jar (unjarring the dependency jars and jar everything together).  I think Sun really dropped the ball by not providing better support for embedding dependency jars with the application jar.

However, using a custom classloader seems like less of a hack:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-onejar/

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that there is not a newline in your manifest file between the Main-Class and Class-Path entry. You should also ensure that there is a newline after the Class-Path entry.

Also I would recommened that Demo be a public class if it is to be used as the main class.

Comment: then why the jar file is executing, when i am only using the Main-Class tag instead of using both
Main-Class, Class-Path tags......

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the manifest classpath, as the Manifest files has some pretty [strange rules](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest), including the ones for line wrapping.

Instead, build a classpath using command line arguments and invoke your program using the main class argument `java -cp Demo.jar:mysql-connector.jar Demo`

Comment: that's a long list for different purposes....
will u plz tell me the only text which i have to write in manifest.txt
to make my frame visible with title OK....

Comment: As I said, I can only suggest building the classpath with 'java -cp', not with the Manifest.

Comment: mr. robert, thnx for your response.....
i have 1 more question to u,
i am new on this site.
will u plz tell me the use of
link link(on left of flag link) on this page...???